# How to duplicate a whole line in Vim?

Tags: vim, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

How do I duplicate a whole line in **Vim** in a similar way to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in IntelliJ IDEA/ Resharper or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> in **Eclipse**?

Comment: Would you like to duplicate this line? `Y`es `P`lease.   :)

Comment: FWIW I have done vimtutor about a dozen times in the last 2 months and this concept is not covered. It tells how to do “dd” and “v - navigate - y” followed by “p”. It does not tell how to copy a single line without deleting it as is asked here.

Answer (score 3340, accepted):

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> to copy the line (mnemonic: ***y**ank*)

or

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to ***d**elete* the line (Vim copies what you deleted into a clipboard-like "register", like a *cut* operation)

then

<kbd>p</kbd> to ***p**aste* the copied or deleted text *after* the current line

or

<kbd>Shift + P</kbd> to ***p**aste* the copied or deleted text *before* the current line

Comment: An excellent point.  For some reason though, I find hitting y twice is faster for me than SHIFT-y

Comment: @camflan I think the Y should be "copy from the cursor to the end"

Comment: and 2yy can be used to copy 2 lines (and for any other n)

Comment: @nXqd: Yes, a big percentage of users maps `Y` to `y$`.  (Consistent with `D` and `C`; (but not Vi compatible (no one cares.)))  That is even proposed in [`:help Y`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#Y).

Comment: To copy two lines, it's even faster just to go `yj` or `yk`, especially since you don't double up on one character. Plus, `yk` is a backwards version that `2yy` can't do, and you can put the number of lines to reach backwards in `y9j` or `y2k`, etc.. Only difference is that your count has to be `n-1` for a total of `n` lines, but your head can learn that anyway.

Comment: Also, use: yj to copy current line and line below it / yk to copy current line and line above it

Comment: Well, it's not the same behavior as in IntelliJ IDEA where the caret remains on the same place. Either `p`, `P` or `gp` will  reset caret location to column 1

Comment: To overwrite the target line: `Vp`

Comment: If this didn't work for you, you've copied someone else's .vim files and they must not know how to use Vim either.

Comment: This does not seem to preserve the cursor position at all, it moves my cursor to the beginning of the line.

Comment: For some reason "y y" did not work in exc mode.
However, "y 1 y" works!

Comment: `nnoremap <C-d> :copy .<CR>` (read: map Ctrl-D to duplicate the current line in normal mode)
`nnoremap <C-d> yyp` (reda: map Ctrl-D to copy the current line and paste it as a new line below)

Answer (score 497):

Normal mode: see other answers.

The [Ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_%28text_editor%29) way:

- `:t.` will duplicate the line,
- `:t 7` will copy it after line 7,
- `:,+t0` will copy current and next line at the beginning of the file (`,+` is a synonym for the range `.,.+1`),
- `:1,t$` will copy lines from beginning till cursor position to the end (`1,` is a synonym for the range `1,.`).

If you need to move instead of copying, use `:m` instead of `:t`.

This can be really powerful if you combine it with `:g` or `:v`:

- `:v/foo/m$` will move all lines not matching the pattern “foo” to the end of the file.
- `:+,$g/^\s*class\s\+\i\+/t.` will copy all subsequent lines of the form `class xxx` right after the cursor.

Reference: `:help range`, `:help :t`, `:help :g`, `:help :m` and `:help :v`

Comment: do you know if`s there a way to do this in visual mode? One of my most common patterns of usage is like visual select 3 lines + :d or :y, for example..

Comment: When you press `:` in visual mode, it is transformed to `'<,'>` so it pre-selects the line range the visual selection spanned over. So, in visual mode, `:t0` will copy the lines at the beginning.

Comment: For the record: when you type a colon (:) you go into command line mode where you can enter Ex commands. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html Ex commands can be really powerful and terse. The yyp solutions are "Normal mode" commands. If you want to copy/move/delete a far-away line or range of lines an Ex command can be a lot faster.

Comment: Downvoted not due to a problem with the answer as such (although it wouldn't work for my situation, I have no idea the line number I want to duplicate to) but because it REALLY shouldn't be the top / accepted answer for this commonly searched question.

Comment: @mjaggard: accepted answers are always at the top, regardless of their score. Yes I added that answer as a complement, and it seems it suited the OP well.

Comment: `:t.` is the exact answer to the question.

Comment: If you're using relative numbers use `:t +7` or `:t -7`

Comment: @mjaggard, turn on line numbers with `:set number`.
I use `:t` every day, usually copying a line or a range of lines from somewhere else in my buffer (usually with a split so I can see exactly which line number they are, to the line where my cursor is. E.g. if I'm writing a presentation in markdown and want to copy headings across multiple slides, `:367t.`, copy line 367 and put it here.

Comment: This ambers not only the OP's question (one command like those in "IntelliJ IDEA/ Resharper" or "Eclipse"), but it is what I came here looking for: no need to make sure there's an extra line where you want the duplicate. +1

Comment: Thank you for hi lighting me on how to duplicate a line! The answer is forever `:t.` and comment line with `#`

Answer (score 336):

`YP` or `Yp` or `yyp`.

Comment: `Y` is usually remapped to `y$` (yank (copy) until end of line (from current cursor position, not beginning of line)) though.  With this line in `.vimrc`: `:nnoremap Y y$`

Comment: Don't forget poor old `yyP`

Answer (score 309):

[image: copy and paste in vim]

Doesn't get any simpler than this! From normal mode:

```
yy
```

then move to the line you want to paste at and

```
p
```

Comment: What did you use to make the gif?

Comment: @Zoltán you can use LiceCap, which is small size

Comment: gif tools, https://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Answer (score 69):

Do this:

First, <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to copy the current line, and then <kbd>p</kbd> to paste.

Comment: Yes, if the cursor is at the end of the line and you type the space as shown you'll duplicate the line you yanked a 2 lines below the line you yanked.

Answer (score 66):

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

will yank the current line without deleting it

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

will delete the current line

<kbd>p</kbd>

will `put` a line grabbed by either of the previous methods

Comment: This one came first but it's duplicate is accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/73357/1438029

Answer (score 55):

If you want another way:

`"ayy`:
This will store the line in buffer `a`.

`"ap`:
This will put the contents of buffer `a` at the cursor.

There are many variations on this.

`"a5yy`:
This will store the 5 lines in buffer `a`.

See "[Vim help files](https://vimhelp.org/) for more fun.

Comment: Thanks, I used this as a bind: map <Leader>d "ayy"ap

Answer (score 53):

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> - remember it with "yippee!"

Multiple lines with a number in between:

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

Comment: 7yy is equivalent to y7y and is probably easier to remember how to do.

Comment: y7yp (or 7yyp) is rarely useful; the cursor remains on the first line copied so that p pastes the copied lines between the first and second line of the source.  To duplicate a block of lines use 7yyP

Comment: @Nefrubyr or `:.,.+7 copy .+7` :P

Answer (score 32):

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> - paste after

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> - paste before

Comment: Since the line is being duplicated, the end result of the content is the same.

Comment: @A-B-B However, there is a miniature difference here - what line will your cursor land on.

Answer (score 18):

I like:
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (to select the whole line immediately and let you select other lines if you want), y, p

Answer (score 15):

Another option would be to go with:

```
nmap <C-d> mzyyp`z
```

gives you the advantage of preserving the cursor position.

Answer (score 12):

You can also try <C-x><C-l> which will repeat the last line from insert mode and brings you a completion window with all of the lines. It works almost like <C-p>

Comment: This is very useful, but to avoid having to press many keys I have mapped it to just CTRL-L, this is my map:

inoremap ^L ^X^L

Answer (score 10):

For someone who doesn't know vi, some answers from above might mislead him with phrases like "paste ... after/before ***current line***".

It's actually "paste ... after/before ***cursor***".

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> to copy the line

or

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to delete the line

then

<kbd>p</kbd> to paste the copied or deleted text *after* the **cursor**

or

<kbd>P</kbd> to paste the copied or deleted text *before* the **cursor**

For more key bindings, you can visit this site: [vi Complete Key Binding List](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html)

Answer (score 10):

I know I'm late to the party, but whatever; I have this in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <C-d> :copy .<CR>
vnoremap <C-d> :copy '><CR>
```

the `:copy` command just copies the selected line or the range (always whole lines) to below the line number given as its argument.

In normal mode what this does is `copy .` *copy this line to just below this line*.

And in visual mode it turns into `'<,'> copy '>` *copy from start of selection to end of selection to the line below end of selection*.

Comment: ↑↑ best answer here!

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to define a custom keymap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in `.vimrc` to duplicate the current line both in *normal* mode and *insert* mode:

```
" duplicate line in normal mode:
nnoremap <C-D> Yp
" duplicate line in insert mode:
inoremap <C-D> <Esc> Ypi
```

Comment: that is exacly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

Default is <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, but I've been using this rebinding for a year or so and love it:

`` " set Y to duplicate lines, works in visual mode as well.
nnoremap Y yyp
vnoremap Y y`>pgv ``

Answer (score 3):

1 gotcha: when you use "p" to put the line, it puts it *after* the line your cursor is on, so if you want to add the line after the line you're yanking, don't move the cursor down a line before putting the new line.

Comment: or use capital P - put before

Answer (score 3):

For those starting to learn vi, here is a good introduction to vi by listing side by side vi commands to typical Windows GUI Editor cursor movement and shortcut keys. It lists all the basic commands including <kbd>yy</kbd> (copy line) and <kbd>p</kbd> (paste after) or <kbd>P</kbd>(paste before).

[vi (Vim) for Windows Users](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/vi-editor/)

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to duplicate a line and paste it right away below the current like, just like in Sublime <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, then you can add this to your `.vimrc` file.

`nmap <S-C-d> <Esc>Yp`

Or, for Insert mode:

`imap <S-C-d> <Esc>Ypa`

Comment: This leaves insert mode though, and just adding `i` to the end to re-enter it breaks `undo`, so the solution to duplicating lines in insert mode is not as trivial as it seems.

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me:
`imap <S-C-d> <Esc>Ypi`  insert mode and 
`nmap <S-C-d> <Esc>Yp` in normal mode

Answer (score 1):

I like to use this mapping:

```
:nnoremap yp Yp
```

because it makes it consistent to use alongside the native `YP` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to duplicate a line just below, the answers above are correct.

Another common case would be if you are somewhere in your text, and you want to duplicate a line located far away in your buffer, out of sight, and you don't want to go there, for some reason.

In this case:

- begin typing a few letters of the beginning of the line that you want to duplicate;
- hit `Ctrl-X Ctrl-L`: this will bring a pop-up list similar to the autocompletion one (`Ctrl-P and Ctrl-N`);
- navigate up and down through this list with `Ctrl-L` and `Ctrl-N` until you get the line you wish;
- hit `Enter`, and voilà.

I find this particularly handy when you write code.

Answer (score 0):

I use this mapping, which is similar to vscode. I hope it is useful!!!.

```
nnoremap <A-d> :t. <CR>==
inoremap <A-d> <Esc>:t. <CR>==gi
vnoremap <A-d> :t$ <CR>gv=gv
```