# How do I duplicate a whole line in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, text, editor, editing, command

I saw [this same question for VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73319/duplicate-a-whole-line-in-vim#73357) and it has been something that I myself wanted to know how to do for Emacs. In ReSharper I use CTRL-D for this action. What is the least number of commands to perform this in Emacs?

Comment: Of course, it's emacs so TMTOWTDI - there's 22! (and counting) http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThereIsMoreThanOneWayToDoIt

Answer (score 160, accepted):

I use

```
C-a C-SPACE C-n M-w C-y
```

which breaks down to

- `C-a`: move cursor to start of line
- `C-SPACE`: begin a selection ("set mark")
- `C-n`: move cursor to next line
- `M-w`: copy region
- `C-y`: paste ("yank")

The aforementioned

```
C-a C-k C-k C-y C-y
```

amounts to the same thing (TMTOWTDI)

- `C-a`: move cursor to start of line
- `C-k`: cut ("kill") the line
- `C-k`: cut the newline
- `C-y`: paste ("yank") (we're back at square one)
- `C-y`: paste again (now we've got two copies of the line)

These are both embarrassingly verbose compared to `C-d` in your editor, but in Emacs there's always a customization. `C-d` is bound to `delete-char` by default, so how about `C-c C-d`? Just add the following to your `.emacs`:

```
(global-set-key "\C-c\C-d" "\C-a\C- \C-n\M-w\C-y")
```

(@Nathan's elisp version is probably preferable, because it won't break if any of the key bindings are changed.)

Beware: some Emacs modes may reclaim `C-c C-d` to do something else.

Comment: Hi! Be aware that if you have '(setq kill-whole-line t)' you will only need one 'C-k' (solution 2) as it already kills the newline together with the contents of the line. My prefered use of 'C-k'.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: What about `C-S-backspace C-y C-y`?

Comment: Would be nice to have a version that did this without modifying the kill ring or the cursor position

Comment: You think Emacs can't do that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637351/emacs-how-to-delete-text-without-kill-ring

Comment: Somewhat easier is to hit `C-S-Backspace` followed by `C-y` `C-y`. Which means kill current complete line and then put it back twice.

Comment: @tofutim Indeed. In Netbeans I do C-S-down.

Comment: @PeterWood Seriously? You think this operation is _so_ important that it _must_ be mapped to a single keystroke? I do this in Emacs literally every day and the key sequence above never enters my conscious mind.

Comment: what is M-w ? which key to use for that ?

Comment: @Bala "M" is "Meta" (usually Esc or Alt, it depends on your keyboard layout). "M-w" is "Meta" and "w" simultaneously (on my keyboard, "Alt-w").

Comment: This is a bad answer, definitely should not be considered as the accepted answer. Relying on keybindings leads to unexpected consequences, especially when people re-bind default ones.

Comment: You should try the great evil mode

Comment: For those that don't understand why this is so embarrassing: Vim does this with three keystrokes `yyp`.

Answer (score 104):

In addition to the previous answers you can also define your own function to duplicate a line. For example, putting the following in your .emacs file will make C-d duplicate the current line.

```
(defun duplicate-line()
  (interactive)
  (move-beginning-of-line 1)
  (kill-line)
  (yank)
  (open-line 1)
  (next-line 1)
  (yank)
)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'duplicate-line)
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error with this:
`Symbol's function definition is void: move-beginning-of-line`

Comment: The problem with this is that "Del" key is also binded to duplicating the line...

Comment: So, any ideas of how to un-bind `Del` from this function?

Comment: OK, found a solution to reverting `Del` back to normal while keeping the new `C-d`: `(global-set-key (kbd "<delete>") 'delete-char)` needs to be added after the `C-d` definition.

Comment: Trying that on an empty  line results in inserting two lines, instead of only one. I don't know why. Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 79):

Place cursor on line, if not at beginning do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, then:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>

Comment: I don't think the second C-Y is needed.

Comment: it won't be a duplicate without

Comment: Use C-S-Backspace (kill-whole-line) instead of C-k. You don't have to screw with cursor position or killing the newline.

Comment: This works nicely but isn't there a short way to do this?

Answer (score 56):

Instead of `kill-line` (`C-k`) as in `C-a` `C-k` `C-k` `C-y` `C-y`  use the [`kill-whole-line`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Killing-by-Lines.html) command:

```
C-S-Backspace
C-y
C-y
```

The advantages over `C-k` include that it does not matter where point is on the line (unlike `C-k` which requires being at start of the line) and it also kills the newline (again something `C-k` does not do).

Comment: Kudos @RayVega!  I tried this solution and it works like a champ (in my GNU Emacs 23.3.1, anyway). Is this solution not working for some people?  This is the best answer to your (own) question.

Comment: You should accept this answer as the correct one. It does exactly what you asked for, and in "the least number of commands".

Comment: This is probably my favourite approach since it requires the least amounts of keystrokes.

Answer (score 55):

My version of a function to duplicate a line that works nice with undo and doesn't mess with the cursor position. It was the result of a [discussion in gnu.emacs.sources from November 1997](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.sources/browse_thread/thread/c5f2992c108abd76/2810ac8f4fca534c?lnk=gst&q=steiner#2810ac8f4fca534c).

```
(defun duplicate-line (arg)
  "Duplicate current line, leaving point in lower line."
  (interactive "*p")

  ;; save the point for undo
  (setq buffer-undo-list (cons (point) buffer-undo-list))

  ;; local variables for start and end of line
  (let ((bol (save-excursion (beginning-of-line) (point)))
        eol)
    (save-excursion

      ;; don't use forward-line for this, because you would have
      ;; to check whether you are at the end of the buffer
      (end-of-line)
      (setq eol (point))

      ;; store the line and disable the recording of undo information
      (let ((line (buffer-substring bol eol))
            (buffer-undo-list t)
            (count arg))
        ;; insert the line arg times
        (while (> count 0)
          (newline)         ;; because there is no newline in 'line'
          (insert line)
          (setq count (1- count)))
        )

      ;; create the undo information
      (setq buffer-undo-list (cons (cons eol (point)) buffer-undo-list)))
    ) ; end-of-let

  ;; put the point in the lowest line and return
  (next-line arg))
```

Then you can define CTRL-D to call this function:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'duplicate-line)
```

Comment: Excellent! The undo and cursor position feature makes this one the best. Thanks!

Comment: also, on the link there's some code for regions too!

Comment: Works great. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @pesche `crux-duplicate-current-line-or-region` works better for me, because with your function it undos line duplication and last operation also.

Answer (score 34):

Here's yet another function for doing this. My version doesn't touch the kill ring, and the cursor ends up on the new line where it was on the original. It will duplicate the region if it's active (transient mark mode), or default to duplicating the line otherwise. It will also make multiple copies if given a prefix arg, and comment out the original line if given a negative prefix arg (this is useful for testing a different version of a command/statement while keeping the old one).

```
(defun duplicate-line-or-region (&optional n)
  "Duplicate current line, or region if active.
With argument N, make N copies.
With negative N, comment out original line and use the absolute value."
  (interactive "*p")
  (let ((use-region (use-region-p)))
    (save-excursion
      (let ((text (if use-region        ;Get region if active, otherwise line
                      (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))
                    (prog1 (thing-at-point 'line)
                      (end-of-line)
                      (if (< 0 (forward-line 1)) ;Go to beginning of next line, or make a new one
                          (newline))))))
        (dotimes (i (abs (or n 1)))     ;Insert N times, or once if not specified
          (insert text))))
    (if use-region nil                  ;Only if we're working with a line (not a region)
      (let ((pos (- (point) (line-beginning-position)))) ;Save column
        (if (> 0 n)                             ;Comment out original with negative arg
            (comment-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
        (forward-line 1)
        (forward-char pos)))))
```

I have it bound to `C-c d`:

```
(global-set-key [?\C-c ?d] 'duplicate-line-or-region)
```

This should never be re-assigned by a mode or anything because `C-c` followed by a single (unmodified) letter is reserved for user bindings.

Comment: I put this in my .emacs file, but when I try to use `C-c d` I get the error `command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, duplicate-line-or-region`. Any idea what's up? I'm using Emacs 25.1.1 on Windows

Comment: Really nice solution, I appreciate the region feature and the commenting-with-negative-argument feature. Also like the suggested key binding.

Comment: @junius `C-c d` is reserved kbd for `kill-whole-line`, use another kbd.

Answer (score 21):

Nathan's addition to your .emacs file is the way to go but it could be simplified slightly by replacing

```
  (open-line 1)
  (next-line 1)
```

with

```
  (newline)
```

yielding

```
(defun duplicate-line()
  (interactive)
  (move-beginning-of-line 1)
  (kill-line)
  (yank)
  (newline)
  (yank)
)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'duplicate-line)
```

Comment: This is nice. Thanks!

Comment: (progn (beginning-of-line)(insert (thing-at-point 'line)))

Answer (score 9):

install duplicate-thing from melpa:

M-x package-install RET duplicate-thing

and add this keybinding to [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Init-File.html#Init-File) :

(global-set-key (kbd "M-c") 'duplicate-thing)

Comment: Looks like not there by this dates.

Answer (score 5):

I have `copy-from-above-command` bound to a key and use that.  It's provided with XEmacs, but I don't know about GNU Emacs.

> `copy-from-above-command' is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function
>   -- loaded from "/usr/share/xemacs/21.4.15/lisp/misc.elc"
>   (copy-from-above-command &optional
>   ARG)
>
> Documentation: **Copy characters from
>   previous nonblank line**, starting just
>   above point. Copy ARG characters, but
>   not past the end of that line. If no
>   argument given, copy the entire rest
>   of the line. The characters copied are
>   inserted in the buffer before point.

Comment: As for version 23, it is the part of the standard GNU Emacs distribution as well.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be in my version. Does something have to be loaded? My version is `GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (amd64-portbld-freebsd8.1) of 2010-11-14 on [host clipped]`.

Comment: @qmega You need to do (require 'misc).

Answer (score 5):

I don't quite remember how line duplication works anywhere else, but as a former SciTE user I liked one thing about SciTE-way: it doesn't touch the cursor position!
So all the recipies above weren't good enough for me, here's my hippie-version:

```
(defun duplicate-line ()
    "Clone line at cursor, leaving the latter intact."
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion
        (let ((kill-read-only-ok t) deactivate-mark)
            (toggle-read-only 1)
            (kill-whole-line)
            (toggle-read-only 0)
            (yank))))
```

Note that nothing gets actually killed in process, leaving marks and current selection intact.

BTW, why you guys so fond of jerking cursor around when there's this nice'n'clean kill-whole-line thingy (C-S-backspace)?

Answer (score 4):

```
C-a C-k C-k C-y C-y
```

Answer (score 4):

something you might want to have in your .emacs is

```
(setq kill-whole-line t)
```

Which basically kills the entire line plus the newline whenever you invoke kill-line (i.e. via C-k). Then without extra code, you can just do C-a C-k C-y C-y to duplicate the line. It breaks down to

```
C-a go to beginning of line
C-k kill-line (i.e. cut the line into clipboard)
C-y yank (i.e. paste); the first time you get the killed line back; 
    second time gives the duplicated line.
```

But if you use this often then maybe a dedicated key binding might be a better idea, but the advantage of just using C-a C-k C-y C-y is you can duplicate the line elsewhere, instead of just below the current line.

Answer (score 4):

' I wrote my own version of `duplicate-line`, cause I don't want to screw up the killing ring.

```
  (defun jr-duplicate-line ()
    "EASY"
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion
      (let ((line-text (buffer-substring-no-properties
                        (line-beginning-position)
                        (line-end-position))))
        (move-end-of-line 1)
        (newline)
        (insert line-text))))
  (global-set-key "\C-cd" 'jr-duplicate-line)
```

Answer (score 4):

This functionality should match up with JetBrains' implementation in terms of duplicating both by line or region, and then leaving the point and/ or active region as expected:

Just a wrapper to around the interactive form:

```
(defun wrx/duplicate-line-or-region (beg end)
  "Implements functionality of JetBrains' `Command-d' shortcut for `duplicate-line'.
   BEG & END correspond point & mark, smaller first
   `use-region-p' explained: 
   http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12334/elisp-for-applying-command-to-only-the-selected-region#answer-12335"
  (interactive "r")
  (if (use-region-p)
      (wrx/duplicate-region-in-buffer beg end)
    (wrx/duplicate-line-in-buffer)))
```

Which calls this,

```
(defun wrx/duplicate-region-in-buffer (beg end)
  "copy and duplicate context of current active region
   |------------------------+----------------------------|
   |        before          |           after            |
   |------------------------+----------------------------|
   | first <MARK>line here  | first line here            |
   | second item<POINT> now | second item<MARK>line here |
   |                        | second item<POINT> now     |
   |------------------------+----------------------------|
   TODO: Acts funky when point < mark"
  (set-mark-command nil)
  (insert (buffer-substring beg end))
  (setq deactivate-mark nil))
```

Or this

```
(defun wrx/duplicate-line-in-buffer ()
  "Duplicate current line, maintaining column position.
   |--------------------------+--------------------------|
   |          before          |          after           |
   |--------------------------+--------------------------|
   | lorem ipsum<POINT> dolor | lorem ipsum dolor        |
   |                          | lorem ipsum<POINT> dolor |
   |--------------------------+--------------------------|
   TODO: Save history for `Cmd-Z'
   Context: 
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88399/how-do-i-duplicate-a-whole-line-in-emacs#answer-551053"
  (setq columns-over (current-column))
  (save-excursion
    (kill-whole-line)
    (yank)
    (yank))
  (let (v)
    (dotimes (n columns-over v)
      (right-char)
      (setq v (cons n v))))
  (next-line))
```

And then I have this bound to meta+shift+d

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-D") 'wrx/duplicate-line-or-region)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is package called [Avy](https://github.com/abo-abo/avy) It has command avy-copy-line. When you use that command, every line in your window gets letter combination. Then you just have to type combination and you get that line. This also works for region. Then you just have to type two combination.

Here you can see interface:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

because i don't know, i'll start this round of golf with a slowball:

ctrl-k, y, y

Answer (score 3):

The defaults are horrible for this. However, you can extend Emacs to work like SlickEdit and TextMate, that is, copy/cut the current line when no text is selected:

```
(transient-mark-mode t)
(defadvice kill-ring-save (before slick-copy activate compile)
  "When called interactively with no active region, copy a single line instead."
  (interactive
   (if mark-active (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (message "Copied line")
     (list (line-beginning-position)
           (line-beginning-position 2)))))
(defadvice kill-region (before slick-cut activate compile)
  "When called interactively with no active region, kill a single line instead."
  (interactive
   (if mark-active (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (list (line-beginning-position)
           (line-beginning-position 2)))))
```

Place the above in `.emacs`. Then, to copy a line, `M-w`. To delete a line, `C-w`. To duplicate a line, `C-a M-w C-y C-y C-y ...`.

Answer (score 3):

I liked FraGGod's version, except for two things: (1) It doesn't check whether the buffer is already read-only with `(interactive "*")`, and (2) it fails on the last line of the buffer if that last line is empty (as you cannot kill the line in that case), leaving your buffer read-only.

I made the following changes to resolve that:

```
(defun duplicate-line ()
  "Clone line at cursor, leaving the latter intact."
  (interactive "*")
  (save-excursion
    ;; The last line of the buffer cannot be killed
    ;; if it is empty. Instead, simply add a new line.
    (if (and (eobp) (bolp))
        (newline)
      ;; Otherwise kill the whole line, and yank it back.
      (let ((kill-read-only-ok t)
            deactivate-mark)
        (toggle-read-only 1)
        (kill-whole-line)
        (toggle-read-only 0)
        (yank)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

With recent emacs, you can use M-w anywhere in the line to copy it. So it becomes:

```
M-w C-a RET C-y
```

Comment: Really? Which "recent" Emacs would that be? Not the case with 24.4: you get "The mark is not set now, so there is no region."

Comment: current Emacs is 24.5, and `M-w` is bound to `easy-kill`. Check that's what you get when you do `C-h c M-w`

Comment: Didn't work in Emacs 24.5.1.  Copied only from start of line to point at the beginning of the same line after inserting a preceding blank line.

Answer (score 3):

When called interactively with no active region, COPY (M-w) a single line instead :

```
(defadvice kill-ring-save (before slick-copy activate compile)
  "When called interactively with no active region, COPY a single line instead."
  (interactive
   (if mark-active (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (message "Copied line")
     (list (line-beginning-position)
           (line-beginning-position 2)))))
```

When called interactively with no active region, KILL (C-w) a single line instead.

```
(defadvice kill-region (before slick-cut activate compile)
  "When called interactively with no active region, KILL a single line instead."
  (interactive
   (if mark-active (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (message "Killed line")
     (list (line-beginning-position)
           (line-beginning-position 2)))))
```

Also, on a related note:

```
(defun move-line-up ()
  "Move the current line up."
  (interactive)
  (transpose-lines 1)
  (forward-line -2)
  (indent-according-to-mode))

(defun move-line-down ()
  "Move the current line down."
  (interactive)
  (forward-line 1)
  (transpose-lines 1)
  (forward-line -1)
  (indent-according-to-mode))

(global-set-key [(meta shift up)]  'move-line-up)
(global-set-key [(meta shift down)]  'move-line-down)
```

Comment: I love the addition of `move-line-up/down` - for that was going to be my next question!

Answer (score 3):

I saw very complex solutions, anyway...

```
(defun duplicate-line ()
  "Duplicate current line"
  (interactive)
  (kill-whole-line)
  (yank)
  (yank))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M-d") 'duplicate-line)
```

Comment: Note that this will mess with kill ring.

Comment: This appends the line onto itself when it is the last line and the file does not end in a new line

Answer (score 3):

I cannot believe all these complicated solutions. This is two keystrokes:

`<C-S-backspace>` runs the command kill-whole-line

`C-/` runs the command undo

So `<C-S-backspace> C-/` to "copy" a whole line (kill and undo).

You can, of course, combine this with numeric and negative args to kill multiple lines either forward or backward.

Comment: Unfortunately, as was the case for me: "Note that many text terminals will prevent you from typing the key sequence C-S-backspace." https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Killing-by-Lines.html

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>, (position to new location) <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>

Add a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> if you're not starting at the beginning of the line.  And the 2nd <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> is to grab the newline character.  It can be removed if you just want the text.

Comment: This has to be the most straightforward method here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@[Kevin Conner]: Pretty close, so far as I know. The only other thing to consider is turning on `kill-whole-line` to include the newline in the C-k.

Comment: @Allen: remove `[` and `]` in `@[Kevin Conner]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function for duplicating current line. With prefix arguments, it will duplicate the line multiple times. E.g., `C-3 C-S-o` will duplicate the current line three times. Doesn't change kill ring.

```
(defun duplicate-lines (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((arg (if arg arg 1))
         (beg (save-excursion (beginning-of-line) (point)))
         (end (save-excursion (end-of-line) (point)))
         (line (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)))
    (save-excursion
      (end-of-line)
      (open-line arg)
      (setq num 0)
      (while (< num arg)
        (setq num (1+ num))
        (forward-line 1)
        (insert line))
      )))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-o") 'duplicate-lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Spacemacs, you can simply use `duplicate-line-or-region`, bound to:

```
SPC x l d
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a package called 'move-dup' on Melpa that can help you with that.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that package.

Answer (score 1):

I write one for my preference.

```lisp
(defun duplicate-line ()
  "Duplicate current line."
  (interactive)
  (let ((text (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)))
        (cur-col (current-column)))
    (end-of-line) (insert "\n" text)
    (beginning-of-line) (right-char cur-col)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d l") 'duplicate-line)
```

But I found this would have some problem when current line contains multi-byte characters (e.g. CJK characters). If you encounter this issue, try this instead:

```lisp
(defun duplicate-line ()
  "Duplicate current line."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((text (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)))
         (cur-col (length (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-at-bol) (point)))))
    (end-of-line) (insert "\n" text)
    (beginning-of-line) (right-char cur-col)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d l") 'duplicate-line)
```

Answer (score 1):

This feels more natural, with respect to the selected answer by Chris Conway.

```lisp
(global-set-key "\C-c\C-d" "\C-a\C- \C-n\M-w\C-y\C-p\C-e")
```

This allows you to duplicate a line multiple times by simply repeating the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> key strokes.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, binding key strokes to lisp code is a better idea than binding them to another key strokes. With @mw's answer, code duplicates the line and moves the mark to end of new line. This modification keeps the mark position at same column on the new line:

```
fun duplicate-line ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((col (current-column)))
    (move-beginning-of-line 1)
    (kill-line)
    (yank)
    (newline)
    (yank)
    (move-to-column col)))
```

Answer (score 0):

With prefix arguments, and what is (I hope) intuitive behaviour:

```
(defun duplicate-line (&optional arg)
  "Duplicate it. With prefix ARG, duplicate ARG times."
  (interactive "p")
  (next-line 
   (save-excursion 
     (let ((beg (line-beginning-position))
           (end (line-end-position)))
       (copy-region-as-kill beg end)
       (dotimes (num arg arg)
         (end-of-line) (newline)
         (yank))))))
```

The cursor will remain on the last line.
Alternatively, you might want to specify a prefix to duplicate the next few lines at once:

```
(defun duplicate-line (&optional arg)
  "Duplicate it. With prefix ARG, duplicate ARG times."
  (interactive "p")
  (save-excursion 
    (let ((beg (line-beginning-position))
          (end 
           (progn (forward-line (1- arg)) (line-end-position))))
      (copy-region-as-kill beg end)
      (end-of-line) (newline)
      (yank)))
  (next-line arg))
```

I find myself using both often, using a wrapper function to switch the behavior of the prefix argument.

And a keybinding:
`(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-d") 'duplicate-line)`

Answer (score 0):

```
;; http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WholeLineOrRegion#toc2
;; cut, copy, yank
(defadvice kill-ring-save (around slick-copy activate)
  "When called interactively with no active region, copy a single line instead."
  (if (or (use-region-p) (not (called-interactively-p)))
      ad-do-it
    (kill-new (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position)
                                (line-beginning-position 2))
              nil '(yank-line))
    (message "Copied line")))
(defadvice kill-region (around slick-copy activate)
  "When called interactively with no active region, kill a single line instead."
  (if (or (use-region-p) (not (called-interactively-p)))
      ad-do-it
    (kill-new (filter-buffer-substring (line-beginning-position)
                                       (line-beginning-position 2) t)
              nil '(yank-line))))
(defun yank-line (string)
  "Insert STRING above the current line."
  (beginning-of-line)
  (unless (= (elt string (1- (length string))) ?\n)
    (save-excursion (insert "\n")))
  (insert string))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f2>") 'kill-region)    ; cut.
(global-set-key (kbd "<f3>") 'kill-ring-save) ; copy.
(global-set-key (kbd "<f4>") 'yank)           ; paste.
```

add the elisp above to you init.el, and you get cut/copy whole line function now, then you can F3 F4 to duplicate a line.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is Chris Conway's method.

```
C-a C-SPACE C-n M-w C-y
```

That's the default way mandated by EMACS. In my opinion, it's better to use the standard. I am always careful towards customization one's own key-binding in EMACS. EMACS is already powerful enough, I think we should try our best to adapt to its own key-bindings.

Though it's a bit lengthy, but when you are used to it, you can do fast and will find this is fun!

Comment: All things considered, Emacs mandates very little -- the huge win that it gives you is the ease of *customising* it to your own needs. Of course in practice there *are* lots of standard ways of doing things which it's beneficial to stick to, but if you're using "default" Emacs and doing something a harder way than necessary just because you think "it's better to use the standard", you're pretty much doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Emacs has a built-in function `duplicate-line`

`M-x duplicate-line` - would duplicate the current line.

`M-x duplicate-dwim` - would duplicate the selected region or if nothing is marked it would just duplicate the current line.

Answer (score -1):

well ive usually used:

```
Ctl-Space (set the mark)
move to end of line
Ctl-K kill line
Ctl-Y * 2 (yank the line back)
```

there may be a much better way though :P

Comment: Do you mean: `C-a C-SPC C-e M-w RET C-y`?

Comment: yeah :)  that's the precise way hehe.

Comment: @Aurthor Thomas: Why kill? Why not simply copy?

Comment: Arthur Thomas, it is spelled right there! haha.  Ctl-W is fine too.  He was just asking about a single line.  wow.