# How can I limit the size of a buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Is there any way that I can limit the size of a buffer in Emacs? have checked this question already: [Can I limit the length of the compilation buffer in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239201/can-i-limit-the-length-of-the-compilation-buffer-in-emacs) but it's not what I want. I want to restrict the size of a buffer that the user is working on and so he can't put more than the pre-defined size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example for `message-mode` (to put a buffer in this mode type `M-x message-mode`)

```
(define-key message-mode-map [remap self-insert-command]
  '(lambda () 
     (interactive)
     (let ((limit-buffer-size 30))
       (message "buffer-size is %i of %i" (buffer-size) limit-buffer-size)
       (if (< (buffer-size) limit-buffer-size)
       (call-interactively 'self-insert-command)
     (message "Maximum bufer size is %i characters" limit-buffer-size)))))
```

Note that user still can `yank` more characters. Another option is to remap `save-buffer`.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see any way to access this directly, what you can do is this: hook `pre-command-hook` if the command is an `self-insert-command` you can check if `buffer-size` is bellow the length you want. Alternatively you can hook `post-self-insert-hook` to check if the hit the size limit, undo it and print a message. For all this you will need to write a `minor-mode` that is active in your buffer.