# Emacs ESS R buffer scrollback limit

Tags: emacs, ess

The R buffer in Emacs Speaks Statistics seems to slow down significantly which the line count gets high.  Is there a way of limiting the size of the buffer?

Modified this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11255400/1007926, but was unable to fix the problem.

```
(add-hook 'ess-tracebug-mode-hook 'ess-tracebug)
(setq comint-buffer-maximum-size 2000)
```

Is `ess-tracebug` the correct name of the R buffer?  This message appears when the buffer is created:

```
ess-tracebug mode enabled
```

---

This is a partial solution:

```
C-c C-o (comint-kill-output)
Deletes everything from the last command to the current prompt.
```

from here: http://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/packages/html/ess_4.html