# How to stop Emacs from "contaminating" the clipboard?

Tags: emacs, editor, clipboard, copy-paste

Emacs always copies killed/deleted content to the clipboard. I often need to copy and paste content into Emacs but when I delete existing content from Emacs before pasting, the content I would like to paste is lost.

The only solution I found is to use

```
(setq save-interprogram-paste-before-kill t)
```

in order to make sure content copied outside of Emacs stays available in the kill-ring, and people with similar problems seem to be satisfied with this solution. What bothers me about it is that I have to type <kbd>C-y</kbd> *followed by one or more repetitions of* <kbd>M-y</kbd> to get to the content I want to paste.

So my question is: How can I stop Emacs from copying content to the clipboard when I kill/delete it (excluding cases where I delete a region with <kbd>C-w</kbd>)?

Comment: Within the last 2 to 3 weeks there were two threads dealing with a similar issue, but there appears to be a difference between how OSX handles it versus other systems.  What OS are you using, please.

Comment: @lawlist I am using Kubuntu.

Comment: So for example, You press M-d to delete a word and this deleted word is being copied to clipboard and you want to prevent this from happening, am I right? or is that you press Backspace and the deleted text is being copied to clipboard?

Comment: @CarloRodríguez Both cases. I don't want a text to be copied to the clipboard at all, except when I am cut it with `c-w`.

Comment: I just can say you can use [TinyEat](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TinyEat) witch has functionality to delete without saving among other things that you may find useful, so I have `(global-set-key "\M-d" 'tinyeat-forward-preserve)` and `(global-set-key (kbd "C-k") 'tinyeat-kill-line)` but for the case of pressing Backspace and the deleted text being copied to clipboard to me that's pretty weird because that doesn't happens with my Emacs

Comment: Just to clarify: What bothers you about the `save-interprogram-paste-before-kill` solution is that if you copy some content `X` outside of Emacs and then delete some words/lines/etc. inside of Emacs *before* pasting you have to type `C-y` *followed by one or more repetitions of* `M-y` to get to `X`. Is that correct?

Comment: use a clipboard manager then it's no problem if something copied to the clipboard, because you can retrieve past clipboard items from a menu

Comment: @CarloRodríguez, does you meant that you never use such useful keys, as `BackSpace` and `c-BackSpace`? Why?It's just as `c-d` and `m-d`, but reverted, very comfortable.

@itsjeyd, yes, you are correct. I almost don't see an applications to use a killed into a clipboard content, most of the time it just disturbs me, as it overwrites something important there.

@Tom I am using Klipper, but in our case this doesn't differ anyhow from the using `(setq save-interprogram-paste-before-kill t)`.

Comment: @JamesKingsbery sorry that I am write it in comments, but I don't see another way. I am partially disagree with an editing you approved, because 1)write alone code line in the middle of a phrase more elegant with just emphasizing (I mean as it was in the old text), 2) The P.S. now doesn't carry an useful information at all: in the old one I wanted to know, how could a people work with this (may be I am just missing some trick or hack, that all another knows), but now it looks like I am just apologize for something.
Hm, strange, seems I can't write more that one user here...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First off: Emacs has its own internal "clipboard" called "[kill ring](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Kill-Ring.html)" which is separate from the system clipboard.

To make sure the system clipboard always has the latest content you copied *outside* of Emacs, add

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil)
```

to your `.emacs` file. According to the Emacs [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html), this will

> prevent kill and yank commands from accessing the clipboard [...].

Irrespective of whether you've killed text inside of Emacs after copying content outside of it, you can then use the command `x-clipboard-yank` to insert the contents of the *clipboard* into the current buffer. If you want, you can set up a global key binding for this command via

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c y") 'x-clipboard-yank)
```

If necessary, replace `C-c y` with a key binding of your choosing.

Comment: Is there a command to modify the clipboard content despite the `(setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil)`? I mean, in order to bind to a `c-w` key, so I can cut the selected text in the clipboard.

Comment: Funny: the internal Emacs documentation doesn't know about the `x-clipboard-yank` at all, but it works anyway...

Comment: `clipboard-kill-region` (for killing) and `clipboard-kill-ring-save` (for copying) should work. And you can access the built-in documentation for `x-clipboard-yank` via `C-h f x-clipboard-yank RET`.

Comment: Excelent! So, to sum up: I end up with the following configs: 

    `(setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil)
     (global-set-key (kbd "C-y") 'x-clipboard-yank)
     (global-set-key (kbd "C-w") 'clipboard-kill-region)
     (global-set-key (kbd "M-w") 'clipboard-kill-ring-save)`

Comment: I'm back after a while to add that now I also added a keybind `(global-set-key (kbd "s-y") 'yank)`. It is yanks from the kill-ring. I found that the kill-ring sometimes is useful, it is certainly deserves a *separate* keybinds.

Comment: x- prefixed variables are now obsolete. Use select-enable-clipboard and so on instead.

Answer (score 5):

These two settings prevent X clipboard contamination. All kill rings stay intact inside Emacs.

```
  (setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil)
  (setq x-select-enable-primary nil)
```

Comment: I just tried after this configuration was set to delete the text with *m-d*. Alas, the text was copied in the clipboard anyway.

Comment: @YagamyLight How did you "set this configuration"? I tested the code provided in this answer on a KDE system and `(setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil)` successfully prevents deleted content from getting stored in the clipboard.

Comment: @itsjeyd hmm... Strange, but this doesn't work for me at all. I tried to copy the content with m-w, and after this both the m-d and m-backspace combinations overwrite the copied text. Here's my .emacs config: http://pastebin.com/GCRxngrG

Comment: @itsjeyd I just found a funny thing. This does not really overwrite the clipboard right now, if I try to paste the text from there in any other application, the text remains old! The problem remains only in the Emacs: the `c-y` key paste only the last text that I deleted, not the one from the clipboard...

Comment: @YagamyLight Emacs has its own internal "clipboard" called ["kill ring"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Kill-Ring.html) which is separate from the system clipboard. That's why you get the text you last deleted when you type `C-y`.

Comment: @itsjeyd well, then if additionally to this answer, someone also write how to force the `c-y` and `c-w` to work with the system clipboard, the question will be solved. Funny, the <kbd>smthng</kbd> tag doesn't work in comment...

Answer (score 1):

Use `delete-region`. Commonly commands having `delete` in their names don't store the stuff in kill-ring.

Comment: But then I am lose various good keybindings for deletion. As I just looked at the documentation, here is few commands, that have a "delete" in those names.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the specific problem of needing to delete something before pasting in the replacement text, just use `delete-selection-mode`. This makes it so that the region is deleted when you paste.

Comment: Yeah, it might work, ⁺¹. Not a scalable solution though, because e.g. in `evil-mode` I use kill-ring very extensively, however moments when I really need the killed content in system clipboard are whole order of magnitude rarer. And I also use `klipper` *(a clipboard manager)*, and prefer the clipboard history to have rather something useful.