# How to replace a region in emacs with yank buffer contents?

Tags: emacs

When I use VIM or most modeless editors (Eclipse, NetBeans etc.) I frequently do the following. If I have similar text blocks and I need to change them all, I will change one, copy it (or use non-deleting yank), select next block I need and paste the changed version over it. If I do the same thing in emacs (select region and paste with C-y), it doesn't replace the region, it just pastes at the cursor position. What is the way to do this in emacs?

Comment: Having similar text blocks (in your code?), usually suggest that you need some refactoring, e.g. replacing the similar text blocks with a function/method call that contains the "similar text". I guest that's one of the reasons I've never really missed a "replace region" feature in Emacs...

Comment: @slu how do you rename the nice function/method that you've extracted?

Comment: @slu it was clearly an example of wanting to replace a selected region with the clipboard. Your second guessing answer was not in any way constructive and showed a desire to virtue signal over coding practices rather than address the legitimate question.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Add this to your `.emacs`:

```
(delete-selection-mode 1)
```

Anything that writes to the buffer while the region is active will overwrite it, including paste, but also simply typing something or hitting backspace

Comment: Why isn’t this default?

Comment: @mcb Probably the same reason the region wasn't visible by default until recently; standard emacs practice is (or was, maybe) to keep the mark in one spot while you move the point around, and the fact that there's a region between them is irrelevant unless you use a command that specifically operates on it. You don't want to be destroying the region every time you type, and there are commands like `exchange-point-and-mark` to jump to where you left the mark. These days I suspect most people don't use the mark that way, so always showing the region and treating it as "active" is probably ok

Comment: This works when manually typing into marked regions, but not when pasting text. :( Emacs 24 / Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @mcandre Both work for me, on 24.3.1. Anything that writes to the buffer should delete the region if that mode is active

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Somehow, it started working for me. :) Oh well.

Comment: @mcandre how does you managed it to work? I am already using Emacs and the `(delete-selection-mode 1)` for a few months, and the fact that I can't just paste the text pretty annoying.

Comment: @mcandre Oh, never mind: just after the comment I thought that if this doesn't worked for me only, probably I should look if this work without my configs. After a quick search I found the problem: my yank command is `x-clipboard-yank` cuz it more comfortable(with some other settings — I am completely separated the kill ring and the clipboard). So, the problem seems that the `x-clipboard-yank` doesn't work as needed…

Comment: I'll leave a fixed function here just if anyone else suffered of a problem that the `x-cliboard-yank` doesn't replaces a selection despite a «delete-selection-mode» enabled `(defun x-clipboard-yank-fixed ()
  (interactive)
  (when mark-active
   (kill-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
  (x-clipboard-yank))`

Answer (score 16):

Setting `delete-selection-mode`, as Michael suggested, seems the most natural way to do it.

However, that's not what I do :)  Instead, I put the good stuff into a "register" -- for example, register "a" --  with `C-x r x a`.  Then I kill the other copy, and copy the register into the same spot with `C-x r g a`.

This is convenient because killing doesn't affect the registers, so `C-x r g a` always inserts the good stuff.

Answer (score 9):

The default way to do something like this is the not-entirely-elegant following:

1. Get your desired replacement text into the kill ring somehow (e.g., M-w).
2. Highlight the region to be replaced.
3. Delete it (`C-w`).
4. Replace it with the prior-copied region (`C-y`, `M-y`).  This replaces the freshly deleted contents with the exact same text that you just deleted (`C-y`), and then re-replaces it with the next most-recently saved buffer in the buffer ring (`M-y`).

This would get to be a real pain if you wanted to do this 10 times with the same text, as the desired replacement would get pushed farther back in the kill ring each time you deleted a region, so you'd have to call `M-w` an increasing number of times each time you wanted to yank it.

I've also just discovered `M-x delete-region`, thanks to [Emacs: how to delete text without kill ring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637351/emacs-how-to-delete-text-without-kill-ring).  As the question implies, this deletes the offending text without putting it into the kill ring, avoiding the problem of pushing your replacement text further down on the stack.  And, as the relevant response mentions, you can bind this to a shortcut key of your choosing.

Answer (score 4):

The way I do this is:

- go to where you want the new stuff
- paste the good stuff
- your cursor is now between the new stuff and the stuff you want to get rid of
- select forward until everything you want to get rid of is selected
- delete it

It's a slightly different way of thinking about it.  Paste what you want, then get rid of what you don't want, rather than replace what you don't want with what you do.

Answer (score 3):

If you enable CUA-mode, this *paste over selected region* becomes the normal behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone landing on this who doesn't want to change the global setting like me, I use this function and key binding:

```
(defun replace-yank(beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (kill-region beg end)
  (yank 3))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-y") 'replace-yank)
```

I intentionally add the selected text to the kill ring incase I want it later, and yank what was previously first in the ring.

Comment: this doesn't quite behave as expected, why isn't it yank 2?

Answer (score 2):

Use `delete-selection-mode`, so that pasted text replaces the active region.

Use the *secondary selection*, to paste the same text over and over, even if you alternately select a new region to replace.

See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection.

Comment: so that copied text replaces the region.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care to preserve the highlighted text in the kill ring you could use something similar to the answer above by ekneiling

```
(defun replace-yank(beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (delete-region beg end)
  (yank 1))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-y") 'replace-yank)
```

One advantage is the above can be done repeatedly.