# How to force emacs's pasting to behave like in other apps

Tags: emacs, paste

I am new emacs user and one of the things that irritates me is that when I want to replace current selected text with the one from clipboard I need to delete it first. Every other application that I know replaces pasted text with the current selection by default.

Here's a little bit more detailed description:

1. Select some block of text
2. Paste text from clipboard
3. Emacs just pastes text where the cursor was and previously selected text it is still there. I want that selected text was deleted first.

Comment: Check out this blog post, for an alternative path: http://sachachua.com/blog/2015/02/getting-started-emacs-empty-cup/

Comment: `(delete-selection-mode 1)` http://stackoverflow.com/a/2627298/1937596

Comment: @artscan Cool! Doesn't seem work if you use the mouse to yank (paste), though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As artscan wrote in a comment, you can get this functionaly for the normal yank (paste) operations by adding:

```
(delete-selection-mode 1)
```

to your configuration.

If you want yank by mouse to also delete the current selection, you can add:

```
(put 'mouse-yank-primary 'delete-selection 'yank)
```

in your configuration as well.