# How can I copy the end of the line starting one line above the cursor?

Tags: elisp

I want to copy the line above the cursor, but just from the current column to the end of that line.

Here's an illustration:

[image: photo of before action]

[image: photo of result of action]

This was my attempt, but it doesn't work so well :-(

```
(defun dupchar()
  (save-excursion
    (line-move (-1) nil nil nil)
    (setq mychar (thing-at-point 'char))
    (insert mychar))
```

Comment: Can you rephrase that?  I can't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Elaborate on what you mean by not working well.  E.g., what is your expected behavior and what is the behavior you observe.  Also, try formatting your code.

Comment: Please try to get some help with your English next time you ask a question - it is very hard to understand what you wrote above.

Comment: thanks guy the problem not working well maybe cause by (thing-at-point 'char), I want to duplication char same as above line but not success most case insert \n if above line have valid character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
(defun dupchar ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((char-above (save-excursion
                      (line-move -1)
                      (following-char))))
    (unless (eq char-above ?\n)
      (insert char-above))))

(define-key global-map [(meta \")] 'dupchar)
```

A few comments on the function you wrote:

1. You need to use `(interactive)`
   otherwise you can't bind the
   function to a key.
2. It's not a good idea to just
   randomly `setq` things—that creates
   a global variable. In this case you
   don't need a variable at all; you
   can make use of the return value
   from `save-excursion`.  (In the later version of this I needed to use a let.)
3. Parentheses call a function in
   (e)lisp, so you need to use `-1`
   instead of `(-1)`.
4. The 2nd-4th arguments to `'line-move` will default to `nil`, so there's no need to specify them.

(Note: I modified this to stop at the end of the line; it's again hard to understand what you wrote, but this is my best guess.)

Comment: thanks Nicholas I got you solution more beautiful code in lisp :-),  still have a problem if current cursor at the end of line (maybe newline) will not success for dupchar

Comment: What do you want it to do at the end of the line?

Comment: for example I've the line I want duplicate this line char by char so I press RET open new open and press (meta \") the result is not correct

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand.  What result are you getting?  What result do you expect?

Comment: a picture is attached
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2682/4189641600_560be88a71_o.png
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2674/4189645716_998944a657_o.png

Comment: All I can say is that it works for me.  Maybe there's some issue typing M-" on your machine?  You can try M-x dupchar and see if it works instead.  For an example of it in action on my machine, see http://vimeo.com/8211826.

Comment: Thanks again, key binding M-" is working which work well if inside middle of text, but not working if cursor is end of position in current line

Comment: OK, well pick another binding then :-)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you intended to copy the whole end of the previous line with one keystroke. At least I thought this would be useful so I modified Nicholas (thanks!) code to `dupline`:

```
(defun dupline ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((line-above-tail (save-excursion
                           (line-move -1)
                           (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) (line-end-position)))))
    (unless (eq line-above-tail ?\n)
      (insert line-above-tail))))
```

Copying to the end of the line was inspired by [How do I duplicate a whole line in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88399)

Comment: dupline I'm simply using hippie-expand with first char
for dupchar I want to cut half line similar with previous fill few piece and same again :-)