# How to duplicate a line without yanking it?

Tags: vim

I'm currently using `yyp` or `yy(n)p` to duplicate lines. Can I do it without yanking lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `:co.` then the `"` register will be left alone.

Comment: Thank you I used it like this: `nnoremap yyp :co.<CR>`

Answer (score 2):

View [Duplicate a whole line in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73319/duplicate-a-whole-line-in-vim)

Explicitly the not so upvoted answers (like `:t.`). - but why not `yyp`?

Comment: I'm using clipboard as vim's default register. So when I duplicate a line, vim is writing the line over system clipboard.

Comment: Your solution working well too, bu I should accept Josh's answer because he is first. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the line with `dd` and then paste (put) it with `p` multiple times. E.g. `2p` to duplicate.